# Agregar video de YouTube dinámicamente desde un JSON por medio del servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jade

Tengo una sección de noticias, cuya información llega desde un JSON. Lo que quiero hacer, es que si la noticia tiene imagen, se suba, y si tiene foto, se coloque dinámicamente un iframe en el lugar donde iría la foto. Me funcionaba cuando lo tenía con un `ajax`, pero ahora tuve que levantarlas desde el servidor por un tema de los `meta tags` de Facebook.

**JavaScript**

```
exports.rest_news = function (req, res) {
    var dataNews = require('../../public/json/news_' + req.params.post_id + '.json');
    res.render('en/common/news_template', {post_id: req.params.post_id, title: dataNews.title, dataNews: dataNews});

}
```

**Jade**

```
.row.section_content
    .col-md-6.col-md-offset-2.col-custom-offset-content.white_real.section_inner_content

       iframe#YouTubeVideo(style="display: none") #{dataNews.YouTubeID}
       img#thumbnail(src="/images/News/"+dataNews.thumbnail")
       br
       h1#title(post_id=post_id) #{dataNews.title}
       br
       h5#date.Top #{dataNews.date}
       #content !{dataNews.content}
```

Cuando lo tenía con el `ajax`, tenía el siguiente código jQuery:

```
if (dataNews.YouTubeID) {
    $("#YouTubeVideo").css("display", "block").attr("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + dataNews.YouTubeID + "?&amp;");
} else {
    $("#thumbnail").attr("src", "/images/News/" + dataNews.thumbnail);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné con un condicional en el `Jade`, de la siguiente manera:

```
 .row.section_content
        .col-md-6.col-md-offset-2.col-custom-offset-content.white_real.section_inner_content(style='max-width:600px;')

          a#prev.back.pull-right.news_navigation(href='/en/news/'+dataNews.prev)
            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right 
          a#next.next.pull-left.news_navigation(href='/en/news/'+dataNews.next)
            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left

          if dataNews.YouTubeID
            iframe#YouTubeVideo(src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ dataNews.YouTubeID + "?&amp;")
          img#thumbnail(src="/images/News/"+dataNews.thumbnail style="width:100%; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:10px;")
          br
          h1#title(post_id=post_id) #{dataNews.title}
          br
          h5#date.Top #{dataNews.date}


          #content !{dataNews.content}
```